# Entity Framework 4 with SQL Server Express files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, ef-model-first

I know that if you use EF in a model-first manner in VS2010 with a standard SQL Server database then it is easy to apply the generated DDL to the database. Is there an easy way to do this with .mdf files (SQL Server Express Files)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server Express *is* SQL Server. This should "just work."

Comment: Running the SQL generated against an mdf file is failing even though the EF works fine once the SQL is run. It's just a PITA to have to use sqlcmd to run the SQL all the time in an iterative development process.

Comment: What is the specific, exact error?

Comment: Sorry about leaving it this long, it's all sorted now, just needed to run devenv.exe as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it properly, you need to apply the DDL by hand, normally using SQL Server Management Studio. You can alternatively use SQL Compact for development.

Just wanted to get it out there.